# How to load and save the updated data into redis from mysql?

Tags: mysql, redis

How to cache mysql data into redis cache and access the data from cache? And if i update any record in redis how can i update that data in  mysql?

Answer (score 0):

In this make redis as primary data fetcher. while updating in mysql,clear the value in redis. Make a logic to whenever the redis key value is empty query from mysql.

Exact steps to achieve this.,

1)GET FROM REDIS

2)**WHILE UPDATING IN MYSQL, CLEAR THE VALUE IN REDIS**

3)SAVE THE UPDATED VALUE IN REDIS

```
//while updating data
DataUpdata{
  Update in MYSQL;
  clear REDIS;
}
//To store updated data in redis
if(data in redis){
  return data;
}
else{
   query from MYSQL;
   save in REDIS;
   return data;
}
```